# Creating new tables for each model instance in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I'm using `Laravel 5.1` to build an application for creating forms.

Each form will be an instance of the Form model. Each form will potentially have a different range of fields. The possible fields are defined in a Fields table (`i.e: *first_name*, *surname*, *date_of_birth*, *postcode*, etc`). There is a has-many relationship between the Form and the Field models.

To collect the form data, I was considering creating a new table for each Form instance.

For example, the user creates a form with the fields `*first_name*, *surname*, *date_of_birth* and *postcode*`. When the form is added, a table will be created   using

```
 Schema::create('form_' . $form->id, function($table) {[... fields ...}).
```

When a user submits the form, the data will be validated using the Form instance as the model and then inserted into the defined table.

I suspect this is a bad or unorthodox idea (mainly because creating tables on the fly feels risky) but would appreciate a second opinion.

Is there a better way of approaching this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right to trust your suspicion that something doesn't quite *feel* right about creating tables on the fly. That really isn't a good idea. The user you use to run your application probably shouldn't have the CREATE privilege, but that's a separate topic.

One solution, to do what you'd like is to have three distinct tables and leverage a polymorphism to store different data types, which represent each form.

## Example Tables

Note: the fields in each table are just given as an example, you'd probably need to expand on them for your own business requirements.

### forms

This table stores each of the forms that have been created.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id | name         | description                       | creator_id |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | Example form | An example of how to setup forms. | 1          |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

### form_fields

This table stores each of the fields that are available in the form. A `required` field shows how you can start building up validation rules. Further columns could be added to expand on this idea (min, max, etc).

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| id | form_id | type      | label         | required | default      |
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 1       | text      | Name          | 1        |              | 
| 2  | 1       | text      | E-mail        | 1        |              | 
| 3  | 1       | textarea  | Comments      | 1        | Your message | 
|--------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

form_data

This table stores the submitted data for each form.

```
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| id | form_id | field_id | data            | created_at          |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 1       | 1        | Joe             | 2015-09-02 12:01:00 |
| 2  | 1       | 2        | joe@domain.com  | 2015-09-02 12:01:00 |
| 3  | 1       | 3        | Test comment    | 2015-09-02 12:01:00 |
|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Thanks, BigPun, that makes a lot of sense.

My concern with that arrangement would be the potential size of the form_data table as we're going to be creating a lot of forms and collecting a lot of data. Submissions for each form could tally 30k, so if there's 10 fields for each form, that's potentially 300,000 rows. After 100 forms, that's 30 million rows. I guess an archiving task would need to be scheduled to prevent the table hitting a file size limit.

Comment: Perhaps look at sharding to handle that. I can't really comment because I don't know the business, but http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil is always something I consider when tackling these issues.